# Light Beams not visible when using volumetrics in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

So I am trying to get some nice lightning effects with volumetrics in my scene using a plane and a sun light in addition to my hdri. My volume is definetly visible and if I set the volume higher then 0.5 my sene is getting really dark. The Sun Light is really close and at around 20 strength which lightens up the scene a bit, so I feel like the light and the volume are correct but when I render I dont get the nice light beams people have in their scenes.

I am only rendering around 60 samples right now. Maybe some light settings are wrong?

I am basically doing what he is doing in this yt video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llRkz1gVz6U

Comment: Is it possible that the lighting from the HDRI is "washing out" the volumetric lighting? Try lowering the strength of the _Background Node_ connected to your HDRI texture and see if that helps.

Comment: I just tried and set my hdri to 0 and set the sun light higher but still nothing. 

Is the sun distance or angle importend?